# Images not displaying in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, photobucket

I have a situation where I am trying to display user-generated HTML in a `webview` using `loadData`. My code is something like this:

```
String content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>" +
    "<html><head>" +
    "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />" +
    "</head><body>";
content += htmlStr + "</body></html>";
wv.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

It works pretty well in most cases, but I am having trouble getting certain types of images to display. In most of my testing, inserting `<img src="..."/>` tags worked fine, but I found that links to images on Photobucket would not display at all; I get a little box with question mark in it instead of the image.

Clicking on a link to an image on Photobucket tends to take you to the page on which that image is viewable on their website, rather than just the raw image itself. I have a feeling that the issue is related to this. I suspect that it may be a "Referer" issue, or perhaps user-agent, or something of that nature, but I cannot for the life of me get this to display properly.

I have tried switching to `loadDataWithBaseURL` and providing a `BaseURL` (as I believe this will be used as the referer url) but that made no difference. I have also tried using `loadUrl("http://photobucket..."` instead and providing a `HashMap` with the Referer header manually set, but that did not work either. Actually, switching to `loadUrl` made it immediately redirect to the device's browser to load the Photobucket page. I attempted to provide a custom `WebViewClient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but the best I got it to do was to display the full Photobucket page inside the `WebView`.

I am sure this is not a specific issue with Photobucket, that just happens to be the site that I discovered this problem with while I was testing.

I would really like to figure some way to deal with this situation so that this can work correctly, but I have been as yet unable to find any helpful direction on SO or the internet at large. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would wait until Photobucket finishes their recent updates before further testing...while you stated you are sure it is not a specific issue with Photobucket the internet is now awash with posters not able to view Photobucket linked to images with android based devices.  If your code works with all other images not hosted on photobucket your code is good.